# Rearranging a graph so that certain nodes are not adjacent?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

> EDIT: Precisely, I am trying to find two disjoint independent sets of known size in a graph shaped like a triangular grid, which may have holes and has a variable perimeter shape.

I'm not very well versed in graph theory, so I'm not sure if there exists an efficient solution for this problem. Consider the following graphs:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Wi5Rfbd.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0GFzaDl.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pezW4yk.jpg]

The colors of any two nodes can be swapped. The goal is to ensure that no two red nodes are adjacent, and no two green nodes are adjacent. The edges marked with exclamation points are invalid. Basically, I need to write two algorithms:

- Determine that the nodes in a given graph can be arranged so that red and green nodes are not adjacent to nodes of the same color.
- Actually rearrange the nodes.

I'm a little lost on how to implement this. It's not too difficult to separate the nodes of one color, but repeating the process for the second color may mess up the first color. Without a way to determine whether the graph can actually be arranged properly, this process could loop forever.

Is there some kind of algorithm that I can use/write for this? I'm mainly interested in the first image's graph (a triangular grid), but a generic algorithm would work as well.

Comment: This is a variation of [graph coloring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring), which is NP-Complete. (Main difference is - predefined number of #nodes per color) - I don't believe it makes the problem any easier though.

Comment: Is your graph always [planar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)?

Comment: @deniss yes the graphs I will be using this on will always be planar, because they're really just triangular grids as in the first image. However, there may be holes and the perimeter shape is variable.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's note that the problem is a variant of [graph coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring).

Now, if you only dealing with 2 colors (red,green) - coloring a graph with 2 colors is fairly easy, and is basically done by finding out if the graph is [bipartite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), and coloring each "side" of the graph in one color. Finding if a graph is bipartite is fairly simple.

However, if you want more than two colors, the problem becomes [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), and is actually a variant of the Graph Coloring Problem.

Graph Coloring Problem:

> Given a graph G=(V,E) and a number `k` determine if there is a
>   function `c:V->{1,2.,,,.k}` such that c(v) = v(u) -> (v,u) is not an
>   edge.

Informally, you can color the graph in `k` colors, and you need to determine if there is some coloring such that you never color 2 nodes that share an edge with the same color.

Note that while it seems your problem is slightly easier, since you already know what is the number of nodes in each color, it doesn't really make a difference.

Assume you have a polynomial time algorithm A that solves your problem.

Now, given an instance `(G,k)` of graph coloring - there are only `O(n^3)`  possibilities to #color1,#color2,#color3 - so by examining each of these and invoking `A` on it, you can find a polynomial time solution to Graph-Coloring. This will mean [P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), which is most likely (according to most CS researchers) not the case.

---

**tl;dr:**

**For 2 colors**: find out if the graph is bipartite - and give one color to each side of the graph.

**For 3 or more colors**: There is no known efficient solution, and the general belief is one does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, this at least gives me a direction to start looking. The problem I am currently working on only involves triangular grids as in the first picture. Does that make any difference in the solution's complexity?

Comment: @sbking I am certain that not for rectangular grids, I am not sure for triangular grids, never encountered it before - but I believe it doesn't make the problem easier

Comment: How about if we're only worried about the red nodes and not the green ones - I know this isn't a bipartite graph, but considering we don't care if blue nodes are adjacent can we at least reliably rearrange the red ones? It seems like this should be a simpler problem but my current implementation is mostly guess and check.

Comment: @sbking, unfortunately it is not easier, this problem is also NP-hard and related to [maximum independent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) problem. If your graph is planar though, there are polynomial time approximations (see for example [this article](http://www.hse.ru/data/2010/09/24/1223689111/The%20Maximum%20Independent%20Set%20Problem%20in%20Planar%20Graphs.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

I thought this problem would be easier for planar graph, but unfortunately it's not the case. Best match for this problem I was able to find is [minimum sum coloring](http://www.cs.bme.hu/~dmarx/papers/marx-phd.pdf) and [largest bipartite subgraph](ftp://ftp.cs.princeton.edu/techreports/1988/149.pdf).

For largest bipartite subgraph, assume that number of reds + number of greens exactly match the size of largest bipartite subgraph. Then this problem is equivalent to your. Paper claims that it's still NP-hard even for planar graphs.

For minimum sum coloring, assume that red color has weight 1, green color has color 2, and we have infinitely many blue* colors with some weight of >graph size. Then if answer is exactly minimal sum coloring, there is no polynomial algorithm to find it (although paper referes to such algorithm for chordal graphs).

Anyway, it seems that the closer your red+green count to the 'optimal' in some sense subgraph, the more difficult problem is.

If you can afford inexact solution, or relaxed solution then you only spearate, say, reds, you have an option. As I said in comment, approximate solution of maximum independent set problem for planar graph. Then color this set into red and blue colors, if it is large enough.

If you know that red+green is much less than total number of vertices, another approximation can work. Look at introduction chapter of [this article](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2010/111/download/). It claims that:

> For graphs which are promised to have small chromatic number, a better
>   guarantee is known: given a k-colorable graph, an algorithm due to
>   Karger et al. [12] uses semidefinite programming (SDP) to find an
>   independent set of size about Ω(n/∆^(1−2/k)).

Your graph is for sure 4-colorable, so you can count on large enough independent set. The same article states that greedy solution already can find large enough independent set.